# Verifying Python generated SHA256 strings using Ruby

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sha256

I'm converting a Python project to Rails, both of them uses the same database and I'm trying to use Ruby to verify the passwords that are saved using Python library called [passlib.hash.sha256_crypt](https://pythonhosted.org/passlib/lib/passlib.hash.sha256_crypt.html). I want to use Ruby to verify the user input whether it is the valid password compared to the saved password using any Ruby library but couldn't find any suitable gem for that.

Example password saved in SHA256 using Python Passlib library:
`$5$rounds=110000$4QB3mR7z8SVQwVDt$1jT2mdn9XHRD.O8gsCJXoUTDWJSLrY09uD8KZp78ou6`
which is `password`

The gems that I've found are:

1. [Ruby Digest library](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib2.1.0/libdoc/digest/rdoc/Digest.html)
   : not generating in the format of `$5$.....`
2. [Unix Crypt](https://github.com/mogest/unix-crypt) : generate digests in relevant format but unable to verify the result
3. [Gibberish](https://github.com/mdp/gibberish) : only advance in AES mode decryption, not generating in the format of `$5$.....`

Unix Crypt is the most relevant solution but the generated digest for the string "password" is different from the Python generated. I tried to remove the `rounds` from the saved digest and verify it but it failed, I think it's because they are using different `rounds` to generate the digest.

```
[7] pry(main)> UnixCrypt::SHA256.build("password")
=> "$5$qbpSpYyYoTCr0q4G$/jyjVRgg3Y4vQj39f9OWwUQhKOh70bTB50jH7WfsZl2"
[10] pry(main)> UnixCrypt.valid?("password", "$5$rounds=110000$4QB3mR7z8SVQwVDt$1jT2mdn9XHRD.O8gsCJXoUTDWJSLrY09uD8KZp78ou6")
=> false
[11] pry(main)> UnixCrypt.valid?("password", "$5$4QB3mR7z8SVQwVDt$1jT2mdn9XHRD.O8gsCJXoUTDWJSLrY09uD8KZp78ou6")
=> false
```

Based on @Niel Slater's comment, I used UnixCrypt's `build` to rehash "password", and it's still different from the Python hashed string.

```
[81] pry(main)> UnixCrypt::SHA256.build("password", "4QB3mR7z8SVQwVDt", 110000)
=> "$5$rounds=110000$4QB3mR7z8SVQwVDt$hF/KhMEITeydgv58fXf2brManFYwhhy.dMqGnrkrLb1"
```

Any workaround on this, or is there any simpler method to verify the user password in Ruby? I'm not familiar with encryption, any detailed explanation on rounds and digests are welcomed too.

Comment: The strings are different because they include a random *salt* (the value between the 3rd and 4th `$` in the Python version), so you will never see the same hash. You can confirm this by re-hashing "password" in Python, and noticing it is different each time. The failure to validate is more of an issue, and means there is some other difference in the formats and/or algorithms between the python and Ruby versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you think `$5$rounds=110000$4QB3mR7z8SVQwVDt$1jT2mdn9XHRD.O8gsCJXoUTDWJSLrY09uD8KZp78ou6` is a hash of `password` for some reason. It is not.

In Python:

```
hash = sha256_crypt.encrypt("password", rounds=110000, salt='4QB3mR7z8SVQwVDt')
# '$5$rounds=110000$4QB3mR7z8SVQwVDt$hF/KhMEITeydgv58fXf2brManFYwhhy.dMqGnrkrLb1'
```

In Ruby:

```
UnixCrypt::SHA256.build("password",'4QB3mR7z8SVQwVDt', 110000 )
# "$5$rounds=110000$4QB3mR7z8SVQwVDt$hF/KhMEITeydgv58fXf2brManFYwhhy.dMqGnrkrLb1"
```

Also:

```
UnixCrypt.valid?("password", 
   "$5$rounds=110000$4QB3mR7z8SVQwVDt$hF/KhMEITeydgv58fXf2brManFYwhhy.dMqGnrkrLb1")
# => true
```

So the Ruby gem `unix-crypt` is the simplest choice for your problem, as it matches the Python library `passlib` with the least effort (no need to figure out the details, just use the same params and string values throughout).

Comment: It's my mistake, ended up the original text was not "password" at all. Thanks for the hint! UnixCrypt is the gem, but the README documentation was not detailed enough so I don't know `round` and `salt` options are available too before I found it out in rdoc.

Comment: That's one of those simple mistakes, once made into an assumption for testing, can cost you a lot of head-scratching and lost time. I deleted my comments about possible bugs, looks like Ruby and Python agree very much on the specifics of the algorithm.